# Calculating Bayes decision boundary on a practical example

Tags: classification, bayesian

In "The elements of Statistical Learning", Chapter 2, the following example is presented: first generate $10$ means $m_k$ from a bivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}((1, 0)^t, I)$ and label this class BLUE. Similarly $10$ more is drawn from $\mathcal{N}((0, 1)^t, I)$ and are labelled ORANGE. Then for each class we generate $100$ observations as follows: for each observation pick $m_k$ at random with probability $1/10$ and then generate a $\mathcal{N}(m_k, I/5)$.

At the end of that chapter there's a question (Exercise 2.2):

> Show how to compute the Bayes decision boundary for the simulation example.

In an unofficial [solution manual](http://waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Hastie/WriteUp/weatherwax_epstein_hastie_solutions_manual.pdf) for the book the following answer is present:

> For this problem one is supposed to regard the points $p_i$ and $q_i$ below
>   as fixed.  If one does not do this, and instead averages over possible
>   choices, then since the controlling points are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and all
>   probabilities are otherwise symmetric between these points when one
>   integrates out all the variation, the answer must be that the boundary is the
>   perpendicular bisector of the interval joining these two points.  The
>   simulation draws 10 points $p_1, \dots , p_{10} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ from
>   $\mathcal{N}((1, 0)^t, I)$, and $10$ points $q_1, \dots, q_{10} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ from $\mathcal{N}((0, 1)^t, I)$. The formula for the Bayes
>   decision boundary is given by equating likelihoods. We get an equation in the
>   unknown $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$, giving a curve in the plane:
>
> $$\sum_i \exp \left( -5 ||p_i - z||^2 / 2\right) = \sum_j \exp \left( -5 ||q_j - z||^2 / 2\right).$$
>
> In this solution, the boundary is given as the equation of equality between
>   the two probabilities, with the $p_i$ and $q_j$ constant and fixed by
>   previously performed sampling. Each time one re-samples the $p_i$ and $q_j$,
>   one obtains a different Bayes decision boundary.

I have a few questions about the proposed solution:

1) Why likelihoods are just sums.

2) Why can we keep $p_i$ and $q_j$ fixed (the reasoning isn't clear)? Why the answer must be that the boundary is perpendicular bisector?

3) Shouldn't summation indices range over a set $[1, \dots, 100]$?

Answer (score 1):

1) I am guessing that the likelihoods are sums because the gaussian means are extracted with equal probability. Actually all members of the sum should have a 1/10 weight but because all them have the same weight it was simply ignored. 
2) The data were generated with the given pi and qj - that is why they are fixed
3) They are only 10 gaussians for each of the two classes - you do not need to sum to 100.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) "Why likelihoods are just sums."?

The answer in the unofficial solutions manual has lots of typos in it (and I am not at all sure that it is an answer to the question asked in the  OP's first paragraph).  In particular, I believe that the likelihoods are stated incorrectly with the summation signs are in the wrong place. Most likely, they should be of the form 
$$C\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k -z\rVert^2\right]  = C\exp\left[-\frac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k -z\rVert^2\right]$$
and 
$$C\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert q_k -z\rVert^2\right]  = C\exp\left[-\frac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert q_k -z\rVert^2\right].$$
Note that since the variance is $\frac 15$, the $p_k$'s are clustered around $(1,0)$ while the $q_k$'s are clustered around $(0,1)$.

The *maximum likelihood decision regions* (which is the same as the Bayesian decision regions for prior probabilities $\pi_0 = \pi_1 = \frac 12$) then are the sets of points in $\mathbb R^2$ for which
\begin{align}
C\exp\left[-\frac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k -z\rVert^2\right]
&\gtrless C\exp\left[-\frac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert q_k -z\rVert^2\right]\\
&\Downarrow\\
\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k -z\rVert^2 &\lessgtr \sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert q_k -z\rVert^2\\
&\Downarrow\\
\sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k \rVert^2 -2 \langle p_k, z \rangle + \lVert z\rVert^2 &\lessgtr \sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert q_k \rVert^2 -2 \langle q_k, z \rangle + \lVert z\rVert^2\\
&\Downarrow\\
D &\lessgtr \sum_{k=1}^{10} \langle p_k-q_k, z \rangle 
\end{align}
where $D = \frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^{10}\lVert p_k \rVert^2 - \lVert q_k \rVert^2$
So, the decision region boundary is the set of points where a *linear function* of $z\in \mathbb R^2$ equals a constant, that is, it is a straight line, and a little thought will show why this straight line is perpendicular to the line through $\bar{p} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_k p_k$ and
$\bar{q} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_k q_k$.